# How to specify priors distributions for variable transformation parameters in rstanarm which are external to the model?

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, mixed-models, rstanarm

Suppose, the response y can be modeled by the following generic equation:

`y = a + b1*x1`,
where `x1 = func(p,q,r)`

Standard functions provided by rstanarm allow to specify the prior distributions for the coefficients `(b1)` and intercept `(a)`.

Do functions in rstanarm such as stan_lmer have a provision to provide prior distributions for the parameters `(p,q,r)` which are external to model?

Comment: If what you are trying to do cannot be accomplished with `rstanarm::stan_nlmer` or `rstanarm::stan_gamm4`, then no.

Comment: What are the possible alternatives? Can we extract the stan_lmer model code and add external priors?

Can brms package help in any way for fitting custom lmer models?

Comment: Yes, the `stan_lmer` code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstanarm/blob/master/src/stan_files/continuous.stan), the `make_stancode` function in brms makes the Stan code it uses, and in situations like this, it is often best to write the Stan code yourself.